# How to append images into local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append images into local storage.

I have a div that I would like to hold all these images. Something as simple as:

```
<div id="imageContainer">
<!--have images go here-->
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
if (Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1) == 1) { // 1/3 chance of conditional being true
  // append some image to #imageContainer and have it locally stored
} else {
  alert('no luck this time...');
}
```

So, each time that above condition is true, how would I append an image into `#imageContainer` and have it locally saved?

Comment: google my son: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: I want to display the images within #imageContainer

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS. thanks for the URL, although it didn't answer OP's question. A good overview of HTML5 Storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the images are small, you could store the image in localStorage as base64 encoded data URI. For example, here is the StackOverflow image as a [data URI](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/10/27/data-uris-explained/):

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABSElEQVR42mP8DwQMeMDfrx8Z7uc6gWn59g0MHEo6KPKMhAwAgZezaxg+7FnBwMzNDzaEVVyWNANA4Fl/LsPnE9vBLpCpWQg2DKcBPx4cZPjz4QEDj0E8ileetMQz/Lh3hYHXwpNBqnAybgNeLg8EG8IioMAg6FjPwKXhDxb//fIxw8PKALBhAi4RDOKpLdgNANn+fn8jw7cbG8F8ZINghoCA4uR9+MPg348PDB+PTwQbBDIUZJCwZz9QQhgsDwoPDAMu7FzIwM7Fy8AnIsMgIq8BZPOBNf96cRFsGBMHP4N45HrcsTAr3QTDJUrGLkDDNBmEuL4xiMlqMXAo2OM2AOSCNw+vM/z89onh6fVTGIalzTyDmZDS09PBnJkzZ2JoABn05uENhk9vngDZnxkM3OMZkNVjGABj4wLIamhjADEApwGkAqoYAABh69q0dfMNBwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

So you would show that in an image like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAA...[snip]" />
```

All you would have to do is create an `<img>` and set the `src` attribute to the data URI.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. And this would work on mobile devices as well?

Comment: @Ferri It will work on mobile browsers, though I am sure there are size limits to the data URI, which I am not sure of what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you were not taking about images and really just meant HTML as the above folks really answered localStorage and dataURL nicely, you would do something like this...

```
localStorage['imageContainerHTML'] = document.getElementById('imageContainer').innerHTML;
```

This is only storing the HTML, not the images. For images, use the advice from the other blokes.